# Why does my collision group script not work for my towers

Tags: lua, collision, roblox

I'm making a tower defense game and I'm trying to make a collision group for my towers so that, they don't hit players or mobs. I made the collision group and the implemented it into my local script inside the GUI for ray casting the tower (the script doesn't allow u too place towers down yet) but I keep getting an error saying "this api can only be used on server.
Here is the script. The part where I try to make the collision group script is in the AddPlaceHolder function. In my output the error is also specifying lines 33 and 53/54

````
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local camera = workspace.CurrentCamera
local towerToSpawn = nil
local gui = script.Parent
local replicatedstorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local towers = replicatedstorage:WaitForChild("Towers")
local PhysicsService = game:GetService("PhysicsService")

local function MouseRaycast(blacklist)
    
    local mousePosition = UserInputService:GetMouseLocation()

    local mouseRay = camera:ViewportPointToRay(mousePosition.X,mousePosition.Y)
    local raycastParams = RaycastParams.new()
    
    raycastParams.FilterType = Enum.RaycastFilterType.Blacklist
    raycastParams.FilterDescendantsInstances = blacklist
    
    
    local raycastResult = workspace:Raycast(mouseRay.Origin, mouseRay.Direction * 1000, raycastParams)

    return raycastResult
end

local function AddPlaceHolderTower(name)
    local towerExists = towers:FindFirstChild(name)
    if towerExists then
         towerToSpawn = towerExists:Clone()
        towerToSpawn.Parent = workspace.Towers
        
        -- Register the new collision group
        PhysicsService:RegisterCollisionGroup(towerExists)

        -- Disable collisions between objects in the collision group
        PhysicsService:CollisionGroupSetCollidable(towerExists,towerExists, false)
        
        for _, object in ipairs(towerToSpawn:GetDescendants()) do
            PhysicsService:RegisterCollisionGroup("Tower")
            if object:IsA("BasePart") then
                object.CollisionGroup = "Tower"
                object.Material = Enum.Material.ForceField
            end
        end
        
        
        
        
    end
end


gui.Gunslinger.Activated:Connect(function()
    AddPlaceHolderTower("Gunslinger")
    
end)

UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, processed)
    if processed then
        return
    end
    
    if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
        
    end
end)


RunService.RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    if towerToSpawn then
        local result = MouseRaycast({towerToSpawn})
    if result and result.Instance then
        local x = result.Position.X
        local y = result.Position.Y + towerToSpawn.Humanoid.HipHeight + (towerToSpawn.PrimaryPart.Size.Y * 2)
        local z = result.Position.Z
        
        local cframe = CFrame.new(x,y,z)
        towerToSpawn:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(cframe)
        end
    end 
end) ```
````

Comment: "this api can only be used on server", the error is telling you that this code must be executed in a Script, not a LocalScript

Comment: i tried putting the code in a script but like the raycasting wont work and i cant spawn the unit by using a normal script because of render stepped

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the script by  just copying the local script into a normal script and in the normal script i removed this part.

```
RunService.RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    if towerToSpawn then
        local result = MouseRaycast({towerToSpawn})
    if result and result.Instance then
        local x = result.Position.X
        local y = result.Position.Y + towerToSpawn.Humanoid.HipHeight + (towerToSpawn.PrimaryPart.Size.Y * 2)
        local z = result.Position.Z
        
        local cframe = CFrame.new(x,y,z)
        towerToSpawn:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(cframe)
        end
    end 
end)
```